# How to perform bootstrapping for estimation and inference of quantile regression using multiply imputed data in R?

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice, quantile-regression

I am trying to manually pool results from quantile regression models run on multiply imputed data in R using `mice`. I make use of a bootstrapping procedure to get 95% CIs and P values of the model terms, in which model parameters and their standard errors are obtained after sampling a certain number of rows that is equal to the unique number of participants in my data set. This procedure is repeated 500 times for each of the *m* imputed data sets. Then, as a last step, I pool the estimated coefficients and their standard errors of the resulting 500 * *m* regression models according to Rubin's rules (1987) (see e.g. https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/rubins-rules.html). To speed things up, I use `foreach` to split up the analyses over multiple processor cores and `for` to loop over the *m* imputed data sets.

However, there seems to be a flaw in the part wherein the results are pooled. When I look at the pooled results, I observe that the P values are not in accordance with the 95% CIs (e.g. P < 0.05 when 0 is included in the 95% CI).

To illustrate this issue, I have made a reproducible example, using these publicly available data: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00519/heart_failure_clinical_records_dataset.csv

Because there are no missing data in this data set, I introduce them myself and impute the data (*m* = 10 multiply imputed data sets with 20 iterations). I use `set.seed` for reproducibility.

**Note** that I use `lm` instead of `quantreg::rq` in this example.

```
# load data
projdir <- "my_directory"
d <- read.csv(file = file.path(projdir, 'heart_failure_clinical_records_dataset.csv'))

#### introduce missing values
set.seed(1)

# age
age_miss_tag <- rbinom(nrow(d), 1, 0.3)
d$age[age_miss_tag == 1] <- NA # MCAR
# serum creatinine
creat_miss_tag <- rbinom(nrow(d), 1, 0.3)
d$serum_creatinine[creat_miss_tag == 1 & d$anaemia == 0] <- NA # MAR
# CK
CK_miss_tag <- rbinom(nrow(d), 1, 0.3)
d$creatinine_phosphokinase[CK_miss_tag & d$platelets > median(d$platelets)] <- NA # MAR
# platelets
platelets_miss_tag <- rbinom(nrow(d), 1, 0.3)
d$platelets[platelets_miss_tag == 1] <- NA # MCAR

library(mice); library(mitml); library(miceadds); library(splines); library(foreach); library(doParallel)

# impute data
imp <- mice(d, maxit = 20, m = 10, seed = 2)

# log creatinine
implong <- complete(imp, 'long', include = FALSE)
implong$log_creat <- log(implong$serum_creatinine)
imp <- miceadds::datlist2mids(split(implong, implong$.imp))

# compute values for Boundary.knots
temp <- complete(imp, 'long', include = FALSE)
B_knots <- rowMeans(sapply(split(temp, temp$.imp), function(x) {
  quantile(x$age, c(0.1, 0.9))
}))

# Convert mids object into a datlist
longlist <- miceadds::mids2datlist(imp)

# fit model based on origial data and use the terms in the below foreach loop
# in order to fix the position of the inner knots
fit_orig <- lm(log_creat ~ 
                 
                 # Main effects
                 ns(age, df = 2, B = c(B_knots[1], B_knots[2])) * sex,
               
               data = longlist[[1]])
```

To further speed things up, I use OLS instead of quantile regression here and parallelize the process.

```
# make cluster used in foreach
cores_2_use <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(cores_2_use)
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, iseed = 9956)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# No. of bootstrap samples to be taken
n_iter <- 500

boot.1 <- c()
for(k in seq_along(longlist)){
  boot.1[[k]] <- foreach(i = seq_len(n_iter),
                         .combine = rbind,
                         .packages = c('mice', 'mitml', 'splines')) %dopar% {
                           
                           # store data from which rows can be samples
                           longlist0 <- longlist[[k]]
                           
                           # set seed for reproducibility
                           set.seed(i)
                           
                           # sample rows
                           boot_dat <- longlist0[sample(1:nrow(longlist0), replace = TRUE), ]
                           
                           # linear regression model based on sampled rows
                           fit1 <- lm(terms(fit_orig), data = boot_dat)
                           
                           # save coefficients
                           fit1$coef
                           
                         }
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

As a last step, I pool the results according to Rubin's rules.

```
n_cols <- dim(boot.1[[1]])[2]
list <- c()
for(i in seq_len(n_cols)) {
  
  # extract coefficients
  parameter <- lapply(boot.1, function(x){
    x[,i]
  })
  
  m <- length(parameter)
  for(k in seq_len(m)) {
    names(parameter[[k]]) <- NULL
  }
  
  Q <- sapply(parameter, mean)
  U <- sapply(parameter, var) # (standard error of estimate)^2
  
  #### Pooling
  # Pooled univariate estimate
  qbar <- mean(Q)
  
  # Mean of the variances (i.e. the pooled within-imputation variance)
  ubar <- mean(U)
  
  # Between-imputation variance
  btw_var <- var(Q)
  
  # Total variance of the pooled estimated
  tot_var <- ubar + btw_var + (btw_var / m)
  
  # Relative increase in variance due to non-response
  r_var <- (btw_var + (btw_var / m)) / ubar
  
  # Fraction of missing information
  lambda <- (btw_var + (btw_var / m)) / tot_var
  
  # degrees of freedom for the t-distribution according to Rubin (1987)
  df_old <- (m - 1) / lambda^2
  
  # sample size in the imputed data sets
  n_sample <- nrow(longlist[[1]])
  
  # observed degrees of freedom
  df_observed <- (((n_sample - n_cols) + 1) / ((n_sample - n_cols) + 3)) *
    (n_sample - n_cols) * (1 - lambda)
  
  # adjusted degrees of freedom according to Barnard & Rubin (1999)
  df_adjusted <- (df_old * df_observed) / (df_old + df_observed)
  
  # 95% confidence interval of qbar
  lwr <- qbar - qt(0.975, df_adjusted) * sqrt(tot_var)
  upr <- qbar + qt(0.975, df_adjusted) * sqrt(tot_var)
  
  # F statistic
  q <- ((0 - qbar)^2 / tot_var)^2
  
  # Significance level associated with the null value Q[0]
  p_value <- pf(q, df1 = 1, df2 = df_adjusted, lower.tail = FALSE)
  
  list[[i]] <- cbind(qbar, lwr, upr, p_value)
  
}
names(list) <- colnames(boot.1[[1]])
list
```

Obviously, the P value shown below is not in accordance with the 95% CI (as 0 is included in the CI, so the P value should be ≥0.05).

```
> list
$`(Intercept)`
           qbar         lwr       upr     p_value
[1,] 0.06984595 -0.02210231 0.1617942 0.008828337
```

---

**EDIT** (29 Dec 2021)

As @Gerko Vink notes in his answer, multiple imputation and bootstrapping both induce variance. The variance induced by imputation is taken care of by Rubin's rules, the bootstrap variance is not. Unfortunately, `mice::pool` will not work with the output returned by `quantreg::rq`.

I am aware of constructing bootstrap CIs based on a naive percentile-based approach as shown in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421410) post, but I am inclined to think this is not the correct approach to proceed with.

Does anyone know how to appropriately take care of the extra variance induced by bootstrapping when using `rq`?

---

**EDIT** (30 Dec 2021)

Inspired by [this](https://thestatsgeek.com/2021/09/22/summary-statistics-after-imputation-with-mice/) recent post, I decided not to hit the road of bootstrapping anymore, but instead manually extract the point estimates and variances from each of the imputed data sets and pool them using Rubin's rules. I have posted this approach as answer below. Any input on how to appropriately take care of the extra variance induced by bootstrapping when using `rq` is still very welcome though!

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrapping and multiple imputation both induce variance. The imputation variance is taken care of by Rubin's rules for parameters with normal sampling distributions. The bootstrap variance is not.

Two remarks:

First, there is a small error in your code. You're calculating the bootstrap variance about `Q` in `U <- sapply(parameter, var)`. No need for `U <- U/n_iter`. `U` is already the variance and `sapply(parameter, sd)` would yield the bootstrapped standard error.

Second, you're using bootstrap parameters to calculate a parametric interval and p-value. That seems needlessly complicated and, as you can see, potentially problematic. Why not calculate the bootstrap CI?

See also [this link](https://amices.org/Synthemice/gerko/BootstrapCI_Validity.html) for some inspiration with respect to different means of calculating the CIs and their respective validity.

A small sim that demonstrates that you cannot expect both to be identical for a finite set of bootstrap replications.

```r
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

#fix seed
set.seed(123)

#some data
n = 1000
d <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)

# ci function
fun <- function(x){
  se <- var(x)/length(x)
  lwr <- mean(x) - 1.96 * se
  upr <- mean(x) + 1.96 * se
  ci <- c(lwr, upr)
  return(ci)
}

# bootstrap
boot <- replicate(500, 
                  d[sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)], 
                  simplify = FALSE)

# bootstrapped ci's based on parameters
boot.param.ci <- boot %>% 
  map(~.x %>% fun) %>% 
  do.call("rbind", args = .)

# bootstrap CI
boot.ci <- boot %>% 
  map(~.x %>% mean) %>% 
  unlist %>% 
  quantile(c(.025, .975))

# Overview
data.frame(param = fun(d), 
           boot.param = boot.param.ci %>% colMeans,
           boot.ci = boot.ci)
#>            param boot.param     boot.ci
#> 2.5%  0.01420029 0.01517527 -0.05035913
#> 97.5% 0.01805545 0.01904181  0.07245449
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The following `reprex` also demonstrates that the bootstrap applied to the imputed data yields different variance estimates under the same pooling rules.

```r
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(mice)

#fix seed
set.seed(123)

imp <- mice(boys, 
            m = 10,
            printFlag = FALSE)

imp %>% 
  complete("all") %>% 
  map(~.x %$% 
        lm(age ~ hgt + hc)) %>% 
  pool %>% 
  summary(conf.int = TRUE)
#>          term   estimate   std.error statistic       df    p.value      2.5 %
#> 1 (Intercept) -1.9601179 0.809167659 -2.422388 682.5182 0.01567825 -3.5488747
#> 2         hgt  0.1690468 0.002784939 60.700342 572.1861 0.00000000  0.1635768
#> 3          hc -0.2138941 0.021843724 -9.792018 639.0432 0.00000000 -0.2567883
#>       97.5 %
#> 1 -0.3713610
#> 2  0.1745167
#> 3 -0.1710000

imp %>% 
  complete("all") %>% 
  map(~.x %>% 
        .[sample(1:748, 748, replace = TRUE), ] %$% 
        lm(age ~ hgt + hc)) %>% 
  pool %>% 
  summary(conf.int = TRUE)
#>          term   estimate   std.error statistic       df      p.value      2.5 %
#> 1 (Intercept) -1.9810146 1.253312293 -1.580623 22.57546 1.278746e-01 -4.5763892
#> 2         hgt  0.1689181 0.004124538 40.954423 24.47123 0.000000e+00  0.1604141
#> 3          hc -0.2133606 0.033793045 -6.313743 22.29686 2.217445e-06 -0.2833890
#>       97.5 %
#> 1  0.6143599
#> 2  0.1774221
#> 3 -0.1433322
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! It remains, however, unclear to me how I could appropriately take the extra variance induced by bootstrapping into account in this case. I presume that if this extra variance would be adequately taken into account (next to the within- as well as the between-imputation variance), then the p-values would be in accordance with the CIs.

Comment: By the way, I think you meant `se <- sqrt(var(x)/length(x))` in `fun` of the simulation example.

Comment: I have found a solution, which I posted as answer here, but I have awarded you the bounty worth 50 rep for the effort you have put in.

Answer (score 0):

For quantile regression, `mice::pool` will not work with the output returned by `quantreg::rq`, because (according to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421410) post) there is no agreed upon method to calculate standard errors, which are required to pool results under multiple imputation.

An ad hoc solution would be to manually extract the point estimates and variances from each of the imputed data sets and pool them using Rubin's rules.

First, a `reprex` using `lm` to verify whether results from the manual approach and `mice::pool` are identical.

```
library(mice)

imp <- mice(nhanes, print = FALSE, seed = 123)

# fit linear model
fit <- with(imp, lm(bmi ~ chl + hyp))

# manually pool univariate estimates using Rubin's rules
pool_manual <- \(model_object) {
  m <- length(model_object$analyses)
  Q <- sapply(model_object$analyses, \(x) summary(x)$coefficients[, 'Estimate'])
  U <- sapply(model_object$analyses, \(x) (summary(x)$coefficients[, 'Std. Error'])^2)
  qbar <- rowMeans(Q)
  ubar <- rowMeans(U)
  btw_var <- apply(Q, 1, var)
  tot_var <- ubar + btw_var + (btw_var / m)
  lambda <- (btw_var + (btw_var / m)) / tot_var
  df_old <- (m - 1) / lambda^2
  n_sample <- length(residuals(model_object$analyses[[1]]))
  n_cols <- dim(Q)[1]
  df_com <- n_sample - n_cols
  df_observed <- ((df_com + 1) / (df_com + 3)) * df_com * (1 - lambda)
  df_adjusted <- (df_old * df_observed) / (df_old + df_observed)
  lwr <- qbar - qt(0.975, df_adjusted) * sqrt(tot_var)
  upr <- qbar + qt(0.975, df_adjusted) * sqrt(tot_var)
  q <- (0 - qbar)^2 / tot_var
  p_value <- pf(q, df1 = 1, df2 = df_adjusted, lower.tail = FALSE)
  df <- data.frame(noquote(rownames(Q)), qbar, lwr, upr, p_value)
  rownames(df) <- NULL
  names(df) <- c('term', 'estimate', '2.5 %', '97.5 %', 'p.value')
  return(df)
}
```

Verify.

```
> pool_manual(fit)
         term    estimate       2.5 %      97.5 %     p.value
1 (Intercept) 21.78583831  8.99373786 34.57793875 0.004228746
2         chl  0.03303449 -0.02812005  0.09418903 0.254696358
3         hyp -1.07291395 -5.57406829  3.42824039 0.624035769

> extract <- c('term', 'estimate', '2.5 %', '97.5 %', 'p.value')
> summary(pool(fit), conf.int = TRUE)[, extract]
         term    estimate       2.5 %      97.5 %     p.value
1 (Intercept) 21.78583831  8.99373786 34.57793875 0.004228746
2         chl  0.03303449 -0.02812005  0.09418903 0.254696358
3         hyp -1.07291395 -5.57406829  3.42824039 0.624035769
```

### Quantile regression

Now, let's pool results from `rq` for the expected median of the outcome.

```
library(quantreg)

# fit quantile regression model
fit <- with(imp, rq(bmi ~ chl + hyp, tau = 0.5))
```

To be able to pool results from `rq`, only the summary method used to extract point estimates and variances from each of the imputed data sets needs to be adjusted in `pool_manual`.

```
Q <- sapply(model_object$analyses, \(x) summary.rq(x, covariance = TRUE)$coefficients[, 'Value'])
U <- sapply(model_object$analyses, \(x) (summary.rq(x, covariance = TRUE)$coefficients[, 'Std. Error'])^2)
```

Result

```
> pool_manual(fit)
         term    estimate      2.5 %     97.5 %    p.value
1 (Intercept) 22.23452856  0.8551626 43.6138945 0.04461337
2         chl  0.03487894 -0.0857199  0.1554778 0.47022312
3         hyp -1.43636147 -6.0666990  3.1939761 0.52455041

> summary(pool(fit), conf.int = TRUE)[, extract]
Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ci = TRUE, ...) : 
  unused arguments (effects = "fixed", parametric = TRUE, exponentiate = FALSE)
```